# Forwarding CVAT server hosted on Ethernet to local port via Tailscale

Tags: networking, server, ssh, port-forwarding

I am trying to expose the CVAT server from my company server machine to my local machine.
The CVAT server was hosted using docker by another colleague and I don't know much about it. Here is some details:

I can access to the CVAT server via ethernet network at the company `123.123.123.123:8080` where `123.123.123.123` is the Ethernet address of the server, not localhost. For example
`curl 123.123.123.123:8080` returns the CVAT welcome page but `curl localhost:8080` return 404 not found.

My local machine is connecting to the server machine via Tailscale network. My attempt is to use ssh port forwarding.

```
ssh -L 8080:123.123.123.123:8080 user@tailscale_ip
```

Then on my local machine `curl localhost:8080` returns 404 not found. I believe the port forwarding did succeed however it forwarded `localhost:8080` from my server machine, instead the CVAT server. Noted that before port forwading `curl localhost:8080` would return error on my local machine.

I know that the details provided are very limit. I would provide more as yourr guidance.
Thanks a lot.